# How to get transaction failed reason with transaction hash with web3?

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm trying to get transaction failed reason with transaction hash with web3?

I have checked getTransactionReceipt() method

```
{ blockHash: '0x29b253c6b69bc632535fd3ee20a5fd48a66635b9baea43bc3985d4048c40363e',
  blockNumber: 3345585,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 738250,
  from: '0x01312d9393560dd371fc6ceb0858377ea4f5f96b',
  gasUsed: 93263,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: false,
  to: '0x71c46ed333c35e4e6c62d32dc7c8f00d125b4fee',
  transactionHash: '0x9867604300bb4ea4c0dda68e6ad3a400e7df55e7695aadd80058595815cdae78',
  transactionIndex: 3 }
```

and getTransaction() method

```
{ blockHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0x3e823606431003B42878267faD2B8B520327CC01',
  gas: 7000000,
  gasPrice: '20000000000',
  hash: '0xbe863134a0192ea9ba42f619a98db343ccbae84e3caded7d09ee4db2dab31de0',
  input: '0xd377234b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004df000000000000000000000000bd5dbffe75274258bc9d0d907f957a2d0774d60f',
  nonce: 2844,
  to: '0x2b3b6353e8E9897069E40b15d615AC3bBeEa1cFD',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: '0',
  v: '0x1c',
  r: '0x3244a729240b0c9da3578177d906bb9c3db2db4a8e9844983d8b235e4137d34e',
  s: '0x30a6ca26f46baa0eff3abcd49f7a581e8fde962afa5adb9b03e16c0bc4db0e97' }
```

Both methods do not have any reason field but I have checked in etherscan it's showing the failed reason in the transaction as below image.

[image]
[image]
is there any way to get reason like etherscan using web3? 
I know we can get status with a status key but my concern is I need reason only how transaction got failed.

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

`status: false`

This indicates what you see on etherscan. If you try getting this field through web3, the response is usually `0x0` or `0x1`.

So here you go:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txID, function (e, data) {
            if (e !== null) {
                console.log("Could not find a transaction for your id! ID you provided was " + txID);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status == '0x0') {
                    console.log("The contract execution was not successful, check your transaction !");
                } else {
                    console.log("Execution worked fine!");
                }
```

Comment: Absolutely. The reason why your transaction failed (which it technically didn't) was that the execution of your code lead to a `revert()`. If you would like to find out, why your contract code could not be executed, then this is what you should probably ask.

Comment: Have seen the etherscan Image? In the image, they are showing the exact reason why this transaction got failed. Need this reason with web3js.

Comment: The only information Etherscan gives you is that the transaction was reverted. This is indicated by the `status` field in the transaction receipt. @NikitaFuchs 's code is correct: it translates that `status: false` to a human readable message.

Comment: It's easy to know if the tx success or fail but the question is "get reason like etherscan". So this answer isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using Parity, you can do eth_tracetranssction.

The reason for the reversion will appear in the error field (if not empty — empty means success means receipt.status == 0x1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tenderly API to do it, here is a sample:

GET [https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/{chainId}/tx/{txHash}](https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/%7BchainId%7D/tx/%7BtxHash%7D)

Set the chain id and transaction hash in the request path.

By calling this API, you could check the failure reason in the `error_message` field or in the `stack_trace[i].error`

Here is a sample failed transaction:

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2

As it is polygon and polygon chain id is 137, you could call this API like this:

```
curl 'https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/137/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2' \
      -H 'authority: api.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
      -H 'accept-language: fa,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7' \
      -H 'origin: https://dashboard.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'referer: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/' \
       --compressed
```

This is the API response:

```
{
  "hash": "0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2",
  "error_message": "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance",
  ...
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as a duplicate. May have been better to use the transaction hash in the question.