# Get the real error of transaction failed

Tags: ethers.js

I have already searched the web and on this site there is [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/52117/81415) but with no solution.

I'm using ethers.js on browser with MetaMask.

I need to know the **real reason** for the failure, not just whether it fails or not, as shown here on polygonscan:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's a common problem situation. You can use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) to debug this. Usually you can obtain more information by increasing the gas limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **It can be done!**

[image]

See here how to do it: https://gist.github.com/gluk64/fdea559472d957f1138ed93bcbc6f78a

> ```
> const a = await provider.getTransaction('0xdc6506137b443a6ad6734b0047a6d00d31748110589b379d72461bc57e510e94');
> try {
>   let code = await provider.call(a, a.blockNumber)
> } catch (err) {
>   const code = err.data.replace('Reverted ','');
>   console.log({err});
>   let reason = ethers.utils.toUtf8String('0x' + code.substr(138));
>   console.log('revert reason:', reason);
> }
> ```

I just checked with a real contract released on Polygon Mainnet: the `require` message is obtainable.

Comment: You get the "out of gas" message. But can you get a custom message? That way you could know what went wrong with your smart contract.

Comment: @Sky yes, also the custom message set in `require` appears.

Comment: Could you then make it so that it returns "Print this message if condition1 != contition2" instead of "out of gas"? Because I haven't seen that, anywhere.

Comment: @Sky did you tried this in solidity code? `require(condition, "my message");`

Comment: Yeah, written a number of functions. And I only get a reply in ganache-testNet, but never on the main net.

Comment: @Sky on which network?

Comment: I have a private network on a private server, where I do blockchain development. A clone of ETH main-net

Comment: @Sky I just checked with a real contract released on Polygon Mainnet: the `require` message is obtainable

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer in 2024:**

Here's an example of using [ethers-decode-error](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error) to get the actual error message quite easily:

```typescript
import { ErrorDecoder } from 'ethers-decode-error'

const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create()

const WETH = new ethers.Contract('0xC02aa...756Cc2', abi, provider)
try {
  const tx = await WETH.transfer('0x0', amount)
  await tx.wait()
} catch (err) {
  const { reason } = await errorDecoder.decode(err)
  // Prints "ERC20: transfer to the zero address"
  console.log('Revert reason:', reason)
}
```

It's almost identical to the example in the original answer except that there is now an `ErrorDecoder` and supports ethers v6. You can refer to the [docs here](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error#revertrequire-errors) for more examples

The original answer below was using ethers v5, which you can still refer to if you are using it.

**Original Answer:**

You can check out [ethers-decode-error v1](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error/tree/1.x) for getting the real error of a failed transaction. This utility also allows you to retrieve custom errors if needed.

In the example below, you are able to get the exact actual error message and do whatever you want with it quite easily:

```js
import { decodeError } from 'ethers-decode-error'

const WETH = new ethers.Contract('0xC02aa...756Cc2', abi, provider)
try {
  const tx = await WETH.transfer('0x0', amount)
  await tx.wait()
} catch (err) {
  const { error } = decodeError(err)
  // Prints the real error message "ERC20: transfer to the zero address"
  console.log('Revert reason:', error)
}
```

You can refer to the [v1 docs here](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error/tree/1.x?tab=readme-ov-file#revertrequire-errors) for more examples

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You often get "out of gas" or some other default error, instead of a more detailed answer.

The reason for this is simple. If the transaction fails (for whatever reason), it's reverted and nothing is written into the blockchain.

If I wanted for the smart contract to return a "console log", I would first need to catch the error after it failed. But that is impossible as the transaction is getting reverted immediately after the error appears. Thus your "console log" will never get activated, and thus no detailed error report.

You might wanna try using solidity `require()` function

```
require(condition1 == condition2, "Print this message if condition1 != contition2");
```

However, this never worked for me on the main net. Instead I used local testNet [ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "this will not work on the main net"? The `require` woks also on mainnet, so the message is also dispatched. Isn't true?

Comment: I was never able to get back the message on the main net. Only on Ganache (development tool). If somebody knows why that is, I would love to get an answer.

Comment: see my answer ;-)