# How to get transaction failed reason with ethers.js

Tags: web3js, transactions, ethers.js

Using ethers' waitForTransaction(), getTransactionReceipt() or getTransaction() I can ask for transaction status,
but I need to know the cause of error (as this question: [How to get transaction failed reason with transaction hash with web3?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52117/how-to-get-transaction-failed-reason-with-transaction-hash-with-web3) )
to log it and to take an action over the transaction.

Is still no way by api to know the reason of failure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tenderly API to do it, here is a sample:

GET [https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/{chainId}/tx/{txHash}](https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/%7BchainId%7D/tx/%7BtxHash%7D)

Set the chain id and transaction hash in the request path.

By calling this API, you could check the failure reason in the `error_message` field or in the `stack_trace[i].error`

Here is a sample failed transaction:

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2

As it is polygon and polygon chain id is 137, you could call this API like this:

```
curl 'https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/137/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2' \
      -H 'authority: api.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
      -H 'accept-language: fa,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7' \
      -H 'origin: https://dashboard.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'referer: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/' \
       --compressed
```

This is the API response:

```
{
  "hash": "0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2",
  "error_message": "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance",
  ...
}
```